# /sys/...cpufreq says 1GHz but CPU applet says 1.66GHz

Tags: linux, cpufreq

My old Thinkpad X60 has a tendency to overheat when under load.
I recently tried

```
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq
echo powersave >scaling_governor
while sleep 1; do cat cpuinfo_cur_freq; done
```

This seems to say that my CPU is now limited to 1GHz and all the info I can find under `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` seem to agree.

Yet, my XFCE4's CPU applet shows me values that vary between 1GHz and 1.66GHz depending on what I'm doing (with a solid 1.66GHz while a compilation is in progress).  Also, the temperatures indicated by `sensors` do not seem to be different from what I was seeing before.

So, everything seems to indicate that my scaling_governor setting does not have any real effect and that the cpuinfo_cur_freq from `/sys/devices/system/cpu/` does not reflect reality.

Where is the CPU's frequency controlled nowadays?  Where does XFCE4's CPU applet get its cpu frequency information?

Comment: What do you see in `cpupower frequency-info`? Is there a /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1, etc?

Comment: @grawity: I don't have any `cpupower` command.  And yes, there's a `sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1` which behaves just like the `cpu0` one since both cores are tied to the same clock domain.